# domain-dao-service model dto lazy loading

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a hibernate entity and I have a lazy fetched field in it. Then I have the same TO object and converted them. But, when I convert entity to TO object, I will have to retrieve the lazy field eagerly, but I want to have a lazy field in my TO as well. How to do it gracefully?

```
MyEntity ent = myDao.findByPrimaryKey(key);
MyTO to=myConverter.convertToTO(ent);
to.getLazyField() // should be evaluated only now.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want you lazy field only after the conversion? You would normally convert only when you want the lazy field to be initialized, not when you still need it as lazy. You can implement your converter so it excludes it, and you manually assign it back.

Comment: Didn't understand the question.